# Paste an image from clipboard using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste

How do we paste an image from clipboard into a custom rich text editor using javascript? (ctrl+c and ctrl+v or a snapshot).

Has anyone used Ajax's rich text editor? Does pasting an image from clipboard to Ajax RTE work?

Comment: AJAX is generally considered a technology... has an actual web dev organization seriously named themselves AJAX? They're just asking for trouble.

Comment: Well, considering the name AJAX was ripped off from a mythical greek warrior (no matter what they claim it's an acronym of) what's another layer of ripping off?

Answer (score 45):

Because this question still often shows up in Google's search results, I want to point out this is possible today, <strike>at least in Google Chrome (2011)</strike> in all modern browsers (2018). They implemented it to use in GMail, but it is available for all websites.

[How does the paste image from clipboard functionality work in Gmail and Google Chrome 12+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c)

Comment: It is now possible in other browsers. I am using FF17 and can use imgur.com's paste from clipboard functionality

Comment: @Mr5o1 that worked perfectly for me you should post it as its own answer

Comment: @AlexS hardly seems worh it, maybe OP could add it to this anser.

Answer (score 29):

To help others, I'll leave the link here with the answer made by Nick Rattalack

```
// window.addEventListener('paste', ... or
document.onpaste = function(event){
  var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(items)); // will give you the mime types
  for (index in items) {
    var item = items[index];
    if (item.kind === 'file') {
      var blob = item.getAsFile();
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event){
        console.log(event.target.result)}; // data url!
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
  }
}
```

[How does the paste image from clipboard functionality work in Gmail and Google Chrome 12+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c)

Comment: `url.createObjectURL` somehow create only a URL working in that session, but not for storing in database. `FileReader()` works very well for base64 image.

Comment: You can totally store a blob in a database using `XMLHttpRequest`, without any `FileReader` usage. You can also store any URI (including URLs) in a database in the same fashion, and storing a URI with `data` scheme will actually store the resource itself (since that is how `data` URIs work). What you are trying to describe is that a URL obtained through a call to `URL.createObjectURL` will only work within a particular "session" (depending on user agent) making it meaningless outside that session, e.g. when issuing a request to store some resource in a database.

Answer (score 13):

This is definitely possible now in Chrome and Firefox. I'm not so sure about IE/Safari.

Look at imgur.com, onpaste, and pasteboard.co as examples, and see the [code for pasteboard on github](https://github.com/JoelBesada/pasteboard) as well as [Joel's excellent write up on his blog](http://joelb.me/blog/2011/code-snippet-accessing-clipboard-images-with-javascript/)

For the record, you need the user to press Ctrl+V on your element, and then you can capture the data in the *paste* event handler by reading from `event.clipboardData` but to make it work down-level, you need to be sure focus is on an empty **contenteditable** element, and pull the results from there, which doesn't work well in Firefox 22. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151018/can-one-hack-paste-image-support-into-a-textarea-in-firefox/14423247?noredirect=1#comment25508678_14423247)

Answer (score 10):

For now i found the [clipboardData Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535220(VS.85).aspx#) .

But it retrieve only text format or URL from clipboard.
`clipboardData` is IE only, it works with character string and return null if we paste an image.

a test example

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" id="context"  onClick="paste();">  
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function paste() {  

var sRetrieveData = clipboardData.getData("Text");
document.getElementById('context').value = sRetrieveData;        

}
</script>
```

By default clipboard access is not enabled on firefox, explanation [here](http://support.mozilla.com/fr/kb/Granting+JavaScript+access+to+the+clipboard).
On the other way, [execCommand()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419(VS.85).aspx) only process text values and is not Firefox compliant.

Like the others said, the fact that code works on IE is a security risk, any site can access your clipboard text.

The easiest way to copy images relative URL is to use a java applet, windows activeX plugin, [.net code](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-javascript-web-developers-isbn-978-0-7645-7908-0/53146-paste-clipboard-image.html) or drag and drop it.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve image from clipboard data using javascript?

Comment: You can't.

To be honest i haven't tested with "native security disabled" settings, but as far i searched there is no way for this.

Comment: you can do it in gmail, therefore it's possible.

Answer (score 10):

New browsers, like Firefox 4, support pasting of image data from clipboard into a RTE as [Data URI with encoded PNG Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Advantages). However, most web applications incorrectly parse these Data URIs and discard it. Yahoo mail properly handles. However Gmail and Hotmail discard it. I have notified Google and Microsoft about this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, It's not possible to paste an image from your clipboard to the RTE.

If you copy a blob from a desktop app like Microsoft Word that contains an image and some text, the image will turn up as a broken reference (though the proportions will be correct) and the text will be pasted correctly (formatting will be lost).

The only thing that is possible is to copy an image within the RTE and paste back within the RTE.