# Paste image from clipboard to web form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, flash, clipboard

I see that this has been discussed a few times before, but that was 2010 and before. Now i was writing a new email in my gmail client and noted that i could just paste an image into the mail body / webform.

I was quite happy to see this as i have been looking for a similar solution for a while.

Can anyone provide some details on how this works? Is it Flash? Or some JavaScript?

Comment: I found this similar question which may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934520/how-can-i-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard-into-a-web-form

Comment: Another similar question with some good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript

Answer (score 4):

It is html5 + javascript, and or flash (depends on the browser)
This link should get you strated: http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/

A little warning though, this only works in chrome as of now.

Comment: Too bad..most of my clients dont use Chrome. But, hearing that HTML5 has possibilities like this makes me a bit more happy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative, inspired by Github's image paste. Seems to work with jQuery.

https://github.com/Rovak/InlineAttachment

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From 2011 (which might be a bit out of date now) this link might be a great starting point for Chrome + Firefox: 
 **http://joelb.me/blog/2011/code-snippet-accessing-clipboard-images-with-javascript/**

*(from the guy who built [Pasteboard](http://pasteboard.co/))*

With IE (if anyone still needs to support IE) it sounds like you might need to resort to HTA, ActiveX, Flex, or Java.  Have a look here: 
[Take a screenshot of a webpage with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)