# clipboard to image using asp c# no picturebox

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, clipboard

Hi everyone I've been having a hard time trying to solve this, i'm creating a forum, so i want either in the text box or on button click, get the users print screen and save it to a file and show it in a image,but image only works with imageUrl, so i couldn't get this to work. I've tried this so far but still not working.

```
Image1 = Clipboard.GetImage();
```

Comment: How are you print-screening a client's machine? ASP.NET runs server-side so you can't use it to take a screenshot of a user's computer. Therefore, the `GetImage` method tries to get the image from the server's clipboard, not the user's one.

Comment: the user comments a post, the user pastes his print screen to the comment.

Comment: any ideas on how i can make the user paste and view his printscrren in a image ? then save that image to serverside ? thanks for your help

Comment: You'd be better off allowing a user to upload an image such as how this site works. You can use the `FileUpload` control as [shown here](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/). Be wary of the security considerations when allowing users to upload images. Some of them are [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4535684/187697)

Comment: This has been discussed before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251528/paste-image-from-clipboard-to-web-form

Comment: i already have the user uploading image i was asked if it was possible for the user to paste the printscreen directly in the comment, but i guess its not possible, thanks for your help

Comment: @user2427935 - Try Alexander's link, some of the suggestions may help.