# Get img in MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a working MVC solution which acts as a kind of "IT Helpdesk", I would like to add the functionality of uploading images (easily done by using `<input type="file"..../>`) however as a lot of people will be copying images from the snipping tool, I am trying to allow them to paste images into the form. This bit works as you can see in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lymdmtr7/), however i cannot work out how to then get these images in the controller, if possible at all.

**View**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <label for="fileUploads" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">File(s) Upload</label>
        <div name="fileUploads" id="fileUploads" multiple contenteditable="true" style="outline: 1px solid black; overflow: auto;"></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
document.getElementById("fileUploads").focus();
    document.body.addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.clipboardData.items.length; i++) {
            if (e.clipboardData.items[i].kind == "file" && e.clipboardData.items[i].type == "image/png") {
                // get the blob
                var imageFile = e.clipboardData.items[i].getAsFile();

                // read the blob as a data URL
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onloadend = function (e){
                    // create an image
                    var image = document.createElement("IMG");
                    image.src = this.result;

                    // insert the image
                    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                    range.insertNode(image);
                    range.collapse(false);

                    // set the selection to after the image
                    var selection = window.getSelection();
                    selection.removeAllRanges();
                    selection.addRange(range);
                };

                // TODO: Error Handling!
                // fileReader.onerror = ...

                fileReader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);

                // prevent the default paste action
                e.preventDefault();

                // only paste 1 image at a time
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

[This is where the JQuery came from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6494234/5118056)

The result of this JQuery inserts an `<img>` inside of the `<div>` e.g

`<div><img src="...." /> </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the `<img>` element in the browser contains a base64 encoded image URL right?

Why don't you take the contents of the `src` attribute and post them back to the server?

Code sample to get you started (in php) here:

[How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string)

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect (i used a C# version but it put me on the right tracks) [C# version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400173/converting-a-base-64-string-to-an-image-and-saving-it)