# Is it possible to get clipboard data from a user with either PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

Essentially, if a user visits the page, and they press `ctrl+v`, the image that is currently in their clipboard is pasted. Is this possible? I've been googling around for solutions and couldn't really find anything substantial.

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/imagemanager/integrated_with_tinymce.php

There's an example. Find any image and put it into your clipboard and it will paste it.

Comment: The image is pasted to where? A WYSIWYG editor? An input field? Should the image has to be uploaded in front?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490908/paste-an-image-from-clipboard-using-java-script

Comment: Pasted into anything that you can paste it in really. Would it be possible to paste it into a textbox or an input of sorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some quick google search's and i found an image uploading site which allows you to ctrl-v your picture to be uploaded.

http://snag.gy/

There javascript is mimified so im having difficulties finding the functionality but that link should give you a good start, plus show you that it is possible.

Edit: Some more info:
A blog post explaining how to detect cut, copy and paste on a text field using jquery [link](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/detect-copy-paste-and-cut-operations-on.html)