# How to get print screen data

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)
>   [How does the paste image from clipboard functionality work in Gmail and Google Chrome 12+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c)

Is it possible to get print screen data on JavaScript or in PHP? I've seen this feature in Gmail before wherein I just press print Screen or copy an image to clipboard and when I press ctrl + v it automatically paste the image on the body of the email.

I'm trying to do this on Gmail now but I can't make it work(I wonder why, maybe the browser that I'm using).

Comment: Check this out: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: a related question .. with an accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535471/is-it-possible-to-get-clipboard-data-from-a-user-with-either-php-or-javascript