# How can I paste an image from the clipboard to Kendo UI Editor?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using the Kendo UI Editor widget. I want to paste the content of the print screen. How can I do that?

Regards,

Naidu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490908/paste-an-image-from-clipboard-using-java-script) is a related question. Seems to work in latest Chrome and Firefox. And can be plugged in the Kendo Editor via some code:

```
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");

$(editor.document).on("paste", function(e) {
  var clipboard = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;

  if (clipboard && clipboard.items) {
      var screenshot = clipboard.items[0];

      if (screenshot.kind == "file") {
          var blob = screenshot.getAsFile();

          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function(event){
            var html = kendo.format('<img src="{0}"/>', event.target.result);

            editor.paste(html);
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      }
  }
});
```

And here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/utapal/1/edit

Comment: Thank you. One more question how can i save the pasted value in to database. I mean i need to convert those in to stream and save in to database

Comment: You need to extract the value of the "src" attribute of the image. It contains the image data in base64 format. More info about data URI can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: How can i do that in ie and safari -- Thank you

Comment: You can't in IE. It does not support the standard. Safari should work.

Comment: Is there any alternative to do in ie

Comment: No. As I said IE doesn't support that.

Comment: Not working in firefox, while i am trying to save the image i am getting half of the image (right part of the image is not displaying)

Comment: The above jsbin link is working for me in IE11.