# Can one hack "paste image" support into a textarea in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I was reading through [this article](http://joelb.me/blog/2011/code-snippet-accessing-clipboard-images-with-javascript/) about image pasting in Chrome and Firefox.

To recap, Firefox does not provide any information about the image pasted, the "paste" event handler gets a null `clipboardData` object.

To work around, one places an invisible contenteditable `div` in the DOM and always keeps it in focus, when stuff is pasted it triggers a timeout that checks the contents of the invisible div to grab an image handle.

Is there any way to hack stuff using magic iframes or what-not, short of replacing the textarea with a contenteditable div, to get paste-image-support in Firefox?

<sub>(note: Java and Flash solutions are out of the question)</sub>

Comment: You can focus the content-editable div in the `document.onpaste` method. This should allow you to not force focus on that div the entire time.

Comment: have you tried that? I wonder if its too late when you do that

Comment: I saw the trick being used on another site a while back. I'll see if I can find it if you'd like.

Comment: I've recently made a unified interface to capture the pasted image on desktop browsers. https://github.com/layerssss/paste.js . It now support IE11, Firefox, Chrome. You guys might want to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="paste" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Insert this item into your html then call the following

```
var pasteDiv = $("#paste")[0];
document.body.onpaste = function (event) {
    pasteDiv.focus();
    //do your magic firefox here
};
```

The `onpaste` fires here because you have your `contenteditable` div and you can then tell firefox where to focus this clipboard data. (without having at least one `contenteditable` item the `onpaste` doesn't fire)

For a working sample see: https://gist.github.com/4577472

Comment: So FF22 no longer allows this to work. I have been unable to come up with a work-around.

Comment: Doesn't allow what to work? The diversion of focus during the paste event?

Comment: For what it's worth, they may have drastically changed clipboardData in 22. See the next to last item in the Aurora changelog https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/22.0a2/auroranotes/ and this bug is now marked fixed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=407983

Comment: So yeah, it looks like using clipboardData *should* work now, but doesn't because of https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=861512

Comment: @Jaykul it was the event redirection. I can redirect onpaste to a contenteditable div before the paste event but the image is no longer available. I guess I'll wait to see how Imgur solves this.

Comment: Theirs and onpaste.com and pasteboard.co all work (sorta) ... they don't have the problem of needing to change the focus, because they don't have a textarea they need to get you out of.

Comment: The clipboardData stuff is definitely working now, but is EMPTY when pasting images. It works fine for pasting image FILES though... Anyway, after playing with this for ... far too long, I've filed a [bug against Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=891247).

Comment: Yeah that's exactly the problem I ran into. Thanks for taking the time, man. It's very appreciated by myself and, I'm sure, David Fowler :)

Comment: Ctrl + v is not working sometimes in firefox v-29 browser. If I resize the browser window then I am able to paste. (paste event is triggering). Is there any problem with firefox 29 browser with contenteditable or paste event with keyboard short cuts ?

Comment: @BuildStarted Is there any other work around for this issue ?. I don't understand how it is working if I resize the firefox window? Any clues ? What is really happening while resizing the firefox window?

Comment: I think they have stopped supporting firefox window resize using javascript also ! :(

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't another way.

*Invisible contenteditable div or Java Applets that run in the browser are two methods notwithstanding.

Comment: I have not seen any examples on how to paste images using a flash bridge, I suspect it is not supported