# Can we read image path from clipboard using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to read the image path of the copied image from the clipboard using jquery/javascript?

Comment: This topic may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490908/paste-an-image-from-clipboard-using-javascript

Comment: it'd be amazing if a 7 year old post is relevant to todays browsers