# set src of an image as copied image in clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Is there a way to get an image from web (for example Google Search page), right click - `Copy image address` - and then paste the copied source as `src` for another image?

Something like:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
$('.imga').attr('src', 'src_from_clipboard');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='imga' src='whatever.jpg' alt='img'>
<br><br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste the Image from System in Html page using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498858/paste-the-image-from-system-in-html-page-using-javascript)

Comment: Sure, there's the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, does it work if copied image is from another domain?

Comment: Given your follow-up question, there's something that isn't clear. Are you talking about URLs (`http://example.com/kitten.jpg`) and image tags (`<a src="http://example.com/kitten.jpg">`) or about copying and pasting the actual image contents (blobs and data URIs)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, Suppose I'm on `example.com`. Right click on `kitten.jpg` - `Copy image address`. Go to my page - click on a button and `$('.imga')` becomes `kitten.jpg`. That's what I want.

Comment: I can't speak for all operating systems but I'm pretty sure that Windows doesn't track the source of plain text copied to clipboard.