# Browser file upload handle copy & paste for Images

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to handle copy & paste for images similar to drag & drop in PrimeFaces
I'm handling paste and then pass the files to remote command, but I'm receiving only strings

```js
         window.onload = function() {
                console.log("paste!!");
             const upldFile = document.getElementById('upld');
             upldFile.onpaste = function(e) {
                 console.log("paste");
                 var items = e.clipboardData.items;
                    console.log(items);
                    if(items != undefined){                 
                        handlePaste([{name: 'data', value: JSON.stringify(items) }]);// a call to remote commend
                        }
             }
            }
```

JSF 2.2 
Primefaces 7

Comment: This isn't a PrimeFaces question its a Javascript question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490908/paste-an-image-from-clipboard-using-javascripthttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/490908/paste-an-image-from-clipboard-using-javascript

Comment: and there is nothing jsf-2.2 specific in the question, not even jsf in general

Comment: I'm trying to add Copy & Paste Support for Images in Primefaces fileupload

Comment: Yep by PF upload is just Jquery FileUpload under the covers: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload which is pure Javascript