# Vaadin 23: file upload from clipboard / Ctrl+V

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23, vaadin-upload

**My need**: I'd like to add an "upload from clipboard" functionality into a Vaadin 23 application so that the user can paste a screenshot into an `Upload` field.

**Known pieces of the puzzle**: I know that there is a `paste` event (see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586232/10318272 or here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event ) and there's the Vaadin `Upload` component ( https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/upload ).

**Question**: How can I transfer the pasted data into the `Upload` field?

Comment: If you do come up with a way, you should mention it as a workaround to this enhancement ticket: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/591

Comment: @ollitietavainen : done: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/591#issuecomment-1197048327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why initially intended solution does not work**: It seems that uploading a screenshot via an `Upload` field is not feasible because the [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) (= model of a file input field) does not allow to add/append a new `File` object.

**(Working) Workaround**: So my workaround is a `TextArea` with a `paste`-EventListener that does a remote procedure call of a `@ClientCallable` method at the server.

Left component is the `TextArea`, right component is a preview `Image`.

[image: TextArea plus preview Image]

**Code**:

```
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ClientCallable;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Image;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextArea;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.StreamResource;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.Base64;

public class PasteScreenshotField extends HorizontalLayout {

private final Image previewImg;

public PasteScreenshotField() {
    // This could be any focusable type of component, I guess.
    TextArea textField = new TextArea();
    textField.setWidth("50px");
    textField.setHeight("50px");
    this.add(textField);

    String pasteFunction = "for(const item of event.clipboardData.items) {"
                           + "  if(item.type.startsWith(\"image/\")) {"
                           + "    var blob = item.getAsFile();"
                           + "    var reader = new FileReader();"
                           + "    reader.onload = function(onloadevent) {$1.$server.upload(onloadevent.target.result);};"
                           + "    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);"
                           + "  }"
                           + "}";
    this.getElement().executeJs("$0.addEventListener(\"paste\", event => {"+pasteFunction+"})", textField.getElement(), this);

    // Optional: Preview of the uploaded screenshot
    previewImg = new Image();
    // TODO: Fixed size of 50px x 50px stretches the image. Could be better.
    previewImg.setWidth("50px");
    previewImg.setHeight("50px");
    this.add(previewImg);
}

@ClientCallable()
private void upload(String dataUrl) {
    System.out.println("DataUrl: "+dataUrl);
    if (dataUrl.startsWith("data:")) {
        byte[] imgBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(dataUrl.substring(dataUrl.indexOf(',') + 1));
        // Showing a preview is just one of the possible scenarios.
        // TODO: check filename extension. Maybe it's not a png.
        previewImg.setSrc(new StreamResource("preview.png", () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes)));
    }
}

}
```

**Extendability**: Instead of `previewImg.setSrc` you could do whatever you want with the uploaded file. The preview is just the proof that the screenshot goes to the server (and could go back to the client again).

**Possible connection to `Upload` component**:

If you've got an `Upload` component and want to extend it with this paste functionality, you can register the `paste` listener at the `Upload` component (or at some other component) and instead of `previewImg.setSrc` you just call this (whereas the `onSucceededRunner` is a `BiConsumer<String, String>` in my case that runs the onSucceeded stuff (updating thumbnails, setting attributes at the bound bean, ...)):

```
    String filename = "screenshot.png";
    String mimeType = "image/png";
    OutputStream outputStream = uploadField.getReceiver().receiveUpload(filename, mimeType);
    outputStream.write(imgBytes);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    onSucceededRunner.accept(filename, mimeTypeString);
```

**Final result**:

This is what my custom upload field looks like in the end (assembled from the code above plus an `Upload` field plus a `TextField` for the file name and a thumbnail preview). The user now has to click somewhere at that field (=focus it, because there could be more than one in a form), press Ctrl+V and then a screenshot gets uploaded (if there is any) from clipboard to Vaadin application at the server.

[image: My custom Upload field]