# how to make an input accept an image ctrl ctrl v?

Tags: angular, typescript, image, input

I am working on a project in Angular and need to make an input accept me copying and pasting an image into it, similar to whatsapp web. What is the easiest way to do this?
I have no idea how to start LOL.

Comment: Usually a good start is googling. For instance "site:stackoverflow paste image javascript" will give you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490908/paste-an-image-from-clipboard-using-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333814/how-does-the-paste-image-from-clipboard-functionality-work-in-gmail-and-google-c. And I guess there are also many non-stackoverflow tutorials on it

Comment: Thanks for the links, they will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your one input for this. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rich-editor-test?file=src/editor/editor.html) is a Stackblitz to play.

Here is a simple **editor** component.
*The Code Behind*

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  OnChanges,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.scss']
})
export class Editor implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() value: any;
  @ViewChild('editor') editor: ElementRef;
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();


  ngOnInit() {
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, null);
    this.editor.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    try {
      if (this.editor.nativeElement.innerHTML != this.value) {
        this.editor.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.value;
      }
    } catch (err) {

    }
  }

  exec(a, b = null) {
    document.execCommand(a, false, b);
  };

  onInput(newValue) {
    this.valueChange.emit(newValue);
  }
}
```

*The HTML part*

```
<button (click)="exec('bold')">B</button>
<div contenteditable (input)="onInput($event.target.innerHTML)" class="editor" #editor></div>
```

It's very small. But the `contenteditable` attribute is important. It has **nothing** to do with Angular. It's a standard HTML attribute, which makes elements editable.

With this simple thing you can insert Images, too with `CTRL + V` or mouse right click. But this will only insert a `img` element into the control. So if you copy a image from your pc it will not working. So you need to do other things. First add this to your `HTML Element`:

```
(paste)="onPaste($event)"
```

*And here the code part of this*

```
  onPaste(e) {
    const items = (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
    let blob = null;
    for (const item of items) {
      if (item.type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
        blob = item.getAsFile();
        console.log(blob);
      }
    }
  }
```

With this blob data you can do what you want. Use a `FileReader` or do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the example Flo. It helped a lot to get an idea of how to start.

Comment: Great. If the answer is the right, so you can set it as "answer", too. Thx.